# Don't display the alert box when shutting down Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0, windows-7, process

When I call something like:

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 60");
```

An alert message box appears with a message like "Your computer will shutdown in less than 1 minute". How to I prevent that from appearing? Is there another way to shut-down windows?

Comment: have you tried to use the parameter `/a` ? This parameter aborts a system shutdown

Comment: @Dante but won't that abort the scheduled shutdown?

Comment: if you are wanting to Abort then you should change the question based on your question you appear to want to shutdown windows but in another way.. can you clarify..?

Comment: @ApprenticeHacker Yes! you are right, I misunderstood your question. So, using `/p` paramenter will turn off the computer with no warning but you would have to remove the `/t` parameter

Comment: This is a problem that only requires 60 seconds to solve itself.  Whomever ever actually sees it will appreciate that time to save work in progress.

Comment: @Dante thanks. I'll accept that if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "/p");
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
  Process.Start("shutdown", "-f -t 0");
```